Next.js access (req) in Server Action
So i have a client side where there's a button. The button calls a Server Action (Server Function) and it all works well. But i can't access the request of the client. Such as if i want to rate limit the user so they can't spam it.
request returns undefined.
neither do i want to send their ip from the client because then i would have to trust the client and its easy to spoof the parameters.
'use client';

import { Test } from '@/app/actions/test';

export default function TestPage() {
  return <button onClick={() => Test()}>Test</button>;
}

'use server';

import { NextRequest } from 'next/server';

export async function Test(request: NextRequest) {
  console.log(request);
}


All links on google are purple i have not found a solution to this problem.

What are you trying to extract or use from the request?

Your Test function is the wrong way of calling. You are expecting your server action to pass a callback that provides a request object but this server action doesn't provide a callback object.
If you want a function to provide you with a request object as a callback, you have to use middleware for that. Middleware runs before requests are completed and you will get access to request objects inside the middleware function from where you can limit the user to whatever you want.
you don't have to import NextRequest. Just write in the middleware.js this way:
export function middleware(request) {
  console.log(request);
}

And then you will get every request from the client.
Or
you can use route handlers to get request object as well. At first call the route handler using fetch and send the request object as response and then pass that response as the argument of the Test function.

Yeah i figured. I was testing Server Actions to see if it was possible to step away from API endpoints and only keep endpoints for webhooks. But i figured that it would need some extra steps in order to use it. Went back to using API as i could not select method POST, GET, PATH etc. Thanks for the answer! :)

This answer is incorrect. It does not explain how to access the request object from the serve action but suggests something else unrelated to the question!
